# Javascript functions not working on simple html form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The goal of this html "application" is to run a simple form with the ability to save information that is input into a text box. The "information" that was saved then appears above the textbox with a timestamp on it.

While the html runs fine on an emulator for android, as well as on google chrome, and the .css files are functional as well, the javascript is not working whatsoever from what I can tell. I've included the html index code, as well as the javascript file that I had to edit. The rest of the files I did not include were demo files I had to download from the school, and since I am not expected to edit those, I figure the problem has to be somewhere in the javascript file that I have included here.

Specifically, I had to add the click button functions for "add" and "clear". I guess the only thing you guys could really do is look over the code I have and see if you notice any glaring syntax errors or anything of that nature that I could fix, but I have checked the code several times and I have seen nothing wrong.

**EDIT:** It is now working from my original code that I posted. For some reason unknown to me, I tried running my code off a different computer and it works fully as intended now. At first I thought it was a different computer that made it not work, but after testing it a few times it appears that the code simply didn't have enough time to load (10-15 seconds did it). I was clicking the button and after like 10 tries the content finally loaded like it was supposed to. Thank you everyone who helped me "fix" this. I had been wondering initially if my version of jquery was the problem, since it's an older one. But it appears to be fine.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // read the data from local storage for the items
  var items = PROWEBAPPS.Storage.get("listitems");
  var loadTicks = new Date().getTime();

  function displayItems() {
    loadTicks = new Date().getTime();

    $("#items li[class!='header']").remove();
    if (items) {
      // create list items to display the current items
      for (var ii = 0; ii < items.length; ii++) {
        var itemAge = Math.floor((loadTicks - items[ii].created) / 1000);
        $("#items").append("<li>" + items[ii].title + " (created " + itemAge + "s ago)</li>");
      } // for
    } else {
      $("#items").append("<li>No items</li>");

      // initialise the items array
      items = [];
    } // if..else
  } // displayItems


  $("#add").click(function() {
    items.push({
      title: $("#newtitle").val(),
      created: new Date().getTime()
    });

    // save the items
    PROWEBAPPS.Storage.set("listitems", items);
    displayItems();
  });

  $("#clear").click(function() {
    items = null;
    PROWEBAPPS.Storage.remove("listitems");
    displayItems();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Web Storage Tester</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="css/snippets.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/json2.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/prowebapps.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="webstorage-test.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1 class="fancy">&lt;Christopher Hughes&gt; Web Storage JSON Wrapper</h1>
  <ul id="items">
    <li class="header">Items in Storage (tap to remove)</li>
  </ul>
  <ul id="newitem">
    <li class="header">New Item</li>
    <li class="bordered"><input type="text" id="newtitle" placeholder="Title" /></li>
  </ul>
  <ul id="actions">
    <li><button id="add">Add</button></li>
    <li><button id="clear">Clear</button></li>
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What happens when you click your add button?  Your clear button?  Does anything show up in the console?

Comment: when running your code the only errors I get concern `PROWEBAPPS` variable, so, just for testing purposes, I replaced `var items = PROWEBAPPS.Storage.get("listitems");` with `var items = [];`, removed `PROWEBAPPS.Storage.set("listitems", items);` and `PROWEBAPPS.Storage.remove("listitems");` and then both buttons work fine, so edit your own snippet and try it and see

Comment: do you see any errors if you open your browser's devtools (usually f12 and the "console")?
And where does Prowebapps come from?

Comment: @fennel nothing happens at all.

Comment: @Arikael I have no idea what it is, it's a default javascript file that my school has me loading into our weekly assignments. Neither the textbook nor my professor explains it in detail. This is a beginning level mobile dev course so most of these files are way too complex for me to comprehend. I have mostly basic html and css experience, with a tiny bit of java experience.

Comment: @TophHughes
What do you see when you open your browser's dev tools (f12 then under console)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I commented out all script links except the one I used to store your given code and the jquery cdn.
I moved all script tags to the bottom of the body and in a proper order in the html file.
like so ...

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Web Storage Tester</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;" />
  <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="css/snippets.css" /> -->
</head>

<body>
  <h1 class="fancy">&lt;Christopher Hughes&gt; Web Storage JSON Wrapper</h1>
  <ul id="items">
    <li class="header">Items in Storage (tap to remove)</li>
  </ul>
  <ul id="newitem">
    <li class="header">New Item</li>
    <li class="bordered"><input type="text" id="newtitle" placeholder="Title" /></li>
  </ul>
  <ul id="actions">
    <li><button id="add">Add</button></li>
    <li><button id="clear">Clear</button></li>
  </ul>


  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/json2.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/prowebapps.js"></script> -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

After commenting out your storage variables/code and moving your empty array variable to global scope, not scoped within the if/else statement, it seems to be working fine.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // read the data from local storage for the items
  // var items = PROWEBAPPS.Storage.get("listitems");
  var loadTicks = new Date().getTime();
  var items = [];
  function displayItems() {
    loadTicks = new Date().getTime();

    $("#items li[class!='header']").remove();
    if (items) {
      // create list items to display the current items
      for (var ii = 0; ii < items.length; ii++) {
        var itemAge = Math.floor((loadTicks - items[ii].created) / 1000);
        $("#items").append("<li>" + items[ii].title + " (created " + itemAge + "s ago)</li>");
      } // for
    } else {
      $("#items").append("<li>No items</li>");

      // initialise the items array
 
    } // if..else
  } // displayItems


  $("#add").click(function() {
    items.push({
      title: $("#newtitle").val(),
      created: new Date().getTime()
    });

    // save the items
    //PROWEBAPPS.Storage.set("listitems", items);
    displayItems();
  });

  $("#clear").click(function() {
    items = null;
    PROWEBAPPS.Storage.remove("listitems");
    displayItems();
  });
});
```

Hope this helps

Comment: It does work with the "add" button now, but the "clear" button still does nothing. I should have added (and will now) that the clear button is supposed to do the opposite, and wipe out the stuff that was saved.

Answer (score 0):

I faked your localStorage (PROWEBAPPS) and everything seems to work as expected.  Please revise your question.

See solution:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // -- Fake Local Storage --
  PROWEBAPPS = {
    Storage: {
      get: function(name){ return this[name] || (this[name]=[]) },
      set: function(name,items){this[items] = items },
      remove: function(name,){ this[items] = [] }
    }
  };
  
  // read the data from local storage for the items
  var items = PROWEBAPPS.Storage.get("listitems");
  var loadTicks = new Date().getTime();

  function displayItems() {
    loadTicks = new Date().getTime();

    $("#items li[class!='header']").remove();
    if (items) {
      // create list items to display the current items
      for (var ii = 0; ii < items.length; ii++) {
        var itemAge = Math.floor((loadTicks - items[ii].created) / 1000);
        $("#items").append("<li>" + items[ii].title + " (created " + itemAge + "s ago)</li>");
      } // for
    } else {
      $("#items").append("<li>No items</li>");

      // initialise the items array
      items = [];
    } // if..else
  } // displayItems


  $("#add").click(function() {
    items.push({
      title: $("#newtitle").val(),
      created: new Date().getTime()
    });

    // save the items
    PROWEBAPPS.Storage.set("listitems", items);
    displayItems();
  });

  $("#clear").click(function() {
    items = null;
    PROWEBAPPS.Storage.remove("listitems");
    displayItems();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Web Storage Tester</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="css/snippets.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/json2.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/prowebapps.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="webstorage-test.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1 class="fancy">&lt;Christopher Hughes&gt; Web Storage JSON Wrapper</h1>
  <ul id="items">
    <li class="header">Items in Storage (tap to remove)</li>
  </ul>
  <ul id="newitem">
    <li class="header">New Item</li>
    <li class="bordered"><input type="text" id="newtitle" placeholder="Title" /></li>
  </ul>
  <ul id="actions">
    <li><button id="add">Add</button></li>
    <li><button id="clear">Clear</button></li>
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Is the solution to add that ajax google api at the top?